# Why AngularFire observable does not complete in route resolver? - even after .pipe(take(1))

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire

In my Angular app, I'm using a route resolver to return a 'restaurant' object.
However, when I load the route, it seems like the observable does not complete. I added `.pipe(take(1))` to make sure it completes but that is not working.

Can someone help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

restaurant.resolver.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import {  Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {  TransferState } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Restaurant } from '../restaurants/Interfaces.model';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { first, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { OrderFormService } from '../restaurants/order-form.service';

@Injectable()
export class RestaurantResolver implements Resolve<Restaurant> {

    constructor(
        public afs: AngularFirestore,
        private transferState: TransferState,
        public orderForm: OrderFormService,
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId) {

    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {

            let restaurant = this.afs.doc('restaurants/thaiHouse').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)) 
            console.log('e', restaurant)
            return restaurant

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `valueChanges()` but does it really emit at least once? Btw, why you think it doesn't complete?

Comment: @martin Because of the console.log statement, I know it does emit. So, I run the app, go directly to that route, and then it logs the restaurant object, then it just hangs (doesn't timeout either). The browser just spins so the only thing that makes sense is that this observable is not completing.

Comment: But the console log doesn't mean the Observable emits. It just prints the Observable object to console. Try using for example `tap()` operator in the chain to see if it really emits (`tap(v => console.log(v))`).

Comment: I'm not sure I did this as you intended, but it does print the object, when I do this:
  
let restaurant = this.afs.doc('restaurants/thaiHouse').valueChanges().pipe(
            tap(v => console.log('v', v)),
            take(1))

Comment: Yes that's it. If it logs then `take(1)` will complete the chain so if it appears like it doesn't then the problem will be somewhere else.

Comment: @martin it turns out this is a known issue with the library.Thank you for your help. https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Angularfire library. Hopefully it is fixed soon. See issue documented here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2695